# "Wear mourning" vs "Go into mourning"

Tags: meaning

Are these expressions the same? As far as I can understand some texts I've been reading with these expressions, it seems that they have the same meaning.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't "We're mourning"?  Just wondering as it would sound the same as "wear mourning."

Comment: As for "wearing mourning" you can take a look at this site: http://www.fashion-era.com/mourning_fashion.htm

Comment: I'm not sure about "going into mourning", but if you are wearing mourning, I think it means you are dressed in mourning.

Comment: @JBKing, except "wear mourning" is a set phrase, while "we're mourning" sounds a bit strange: it would be much more likely as "we're in mourning". (Also, in my idiolect at least, "wear" and "we're" don't sound the same.)

Comment: "Mourning-wear" would make sense as fashion for when is in mourning.  If someone recently attended a funeral, there could be times where I'd hear "We're mourning" for why someone doesn't want visitors.  While it is a slip, it would be easily forgiven given the circumstances.

Comment: @JB: As Martha indicated, _wear mourning_ is an [established phrase](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wear+mourning%2Cmourning+wear&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: @Martha "We're mourning" is quite normal as the beginning of a sentence, like "We're mourning the death of my mother." As a complete sentence, "Why are you wearing black?" "We're mourning", sounds just as good to me as "We're in mourning".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they don't have the same meaning, although they are usually somewhat related.

*Go into mourning* means that you enter into a state of grief; it describes a condition of the heart. If I begin to feel sorrow and pain at the loss of a loved one, then I have gone into a state of mourning.

*Wear mourning*, on the other hand, means putting on clothes that display an outward expression of that grief. It is more of a symbolic action.

That all said, the two normally go hand-in-hand. You generally *wear mourning* because you have *gone into mourning*, although there may be some exceptions to that (such as a widow who has murdered her husband, but wants to *look* as though she is grieving in order to allay suspicion).

A [Google books search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22wear%20mourning%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1950,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en) on the expression *wear mourning* reveals some interesting customs across different cultures. For example, some people are (or were) recommended to "wear mourning for a year." The fact that such a predetermined length of time could be prescribed illustrates how there is not always an exact correspondence between the true inward feelings of mourning, and the symbolic act of wearing mourning clothes.

Comment: Very good answer :)

Answer (score 3):

In your linked page, the examples are like

> [subject] wearing mourning dress...

This usage is OK since wearing is the verb and mourning dress is the object.

*go into mourning* means the person starting the process of mourning, as in:

> He will *go* into mourning.

though *go* could be conjugated like

> He *is going* into mourning.

As for *wear mourning*, many examples are like *"they would wear morning clothes"* (here *wear* is a verb rather than noun or part of a noun phrase), but some were like that used in this Wikipedia link [Mourning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mourning) which has related historical information

> Parents would **wear mourning** for a child for "as long as they feel so disposed".

It seems to be mainly of UK usage. I have never heard it used this way. *wear* needs to be the verb, so I guess *mourning* is the object meaning *mourning clothes*.

Answer (score 1):

Interpreted literally, *"wear mourning"* refers to clothing: it means dressing in a way that society associates with bereavement. (This usually means "in all black clothing", although Victorian society had much more complex rules about who wore how much black and for how long.)

However, it's a natural progression from *"wear [a certain type of clothing]"* to *"be in [a certain type of clothing]"*, and from there to *"be in [a state that is associated with said type of clothing]"*. So *"wear mourning"* can, via [metonymy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy), mean the same thing as *"be in mourning"*.

*Go into mourning* refers specifically to the beginning of the state of bereavement. In an of itself, it doesn't say anything about clothing, so you have to evaluate the context (the era, the social class, the religion, even the gender of the subject) to know whether someone who is going into mourning is likely to be wearing black or not. To put it another way, modern people *go into* mourning all the time, but few of them *wear* mourning except maybe to the funeral. (In a sense, people who find "wear mourning" a strange or archaic expression are reacting that way not because the *language* is obsolete, but because the *action* is.)